# How can I calculate distance travelled for a user's journey?

Tags: php, mysql, distance, latitude-longitude

In my database, I have a few thousand rows with the latitude and longitude stores.

**In PHP**, how can I calculate the total distance the user has travelled on their journey stored in my database as recorded latitude and longitude points?

Is there a mathematical equation I can reference or something? In my system I will be performing this calculation on a Queue and then caching it as the user's journey won't change after my system has recorded it so efficiency isn't an issue.

I would ideally like the output to be a total of the distance travelled in miles.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:** Here is a code sample of what I have done so far.

```
$distance = 0;
$earthRadius = 6371;

for($i = 0; $i < $journey->data->count(); $i++)
{
    $currentData = $journey->data->get($i);
    $previousData = $journey->data->get($i-1);

    if($previousData == null) continue;

    $dLat = deg2rad($currentData->latitude - $previousData->latitude);
    $dLon = deg2rad($currentData->longitude - $previousData->longitude);
    $a = sin($dLat / 2) * sin($dLat / 2) + 
         cos(deg2rad($currentData->latitude)) * 
         cos(deg2rad($previousData->latitude)) * 
         sin($dLon / 2) * sin($dLon / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $distance += $earthRadius * $c;
}

// $distance should be a total in kilometers?
```

**Is this correct?**

Comment: Google "Haversine" or "Vincenty" for great circle formulae

Comment: Those only do distance between 2 points, I have about 1000. How would I go about looping this?

Comment: See my added code sample, is it correct?

Comment: How do you go about looping it? With a loop of course, just adding each result to get the sum total

Comment: Forget about the php for now. Just provide some sample data (as a set of DDLs) and a desired result